# PowerBI How to merge two figures that are not based on same measure

Tags: merge, powerbi

How do I merge these two figures together which are both based on another measure? The result of the measure is the same however, they were calculated in a different way due to a change in masterdata. So I am looking for a final chart which contains one line and on the x-axis: 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019.

[image: The two figures]

Comment: You can put multiple measures in the Values box of a line chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add both measure in values field and year on X Axis

[image]